# Log JSF tree components for analyse

Tags: jsf

Is there a procedure that log the complete JSF tree ?

i need to see and analyse the tree.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean debugTree = false;
public static final void logTree(UIComponent cpn, int deep) {
    if (!debugTree)
            return;
    System.out.println(Strings.repeat(" ", 5*deep)+
        cpn.getClass().getSimpleName()+" : "+cpn.getId());
    for (UIComponent child :cpn.getChildren())
        logTree(child, deep+1);
}
```